# How to install IIS and .net 3.5 on windows7

Tags: windows-7

Setting up my deveopment environment, how do I install IIS and asp.net 3.5 on windows7?

Comment: Isn't .NET 3.5 SP1 already on Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way you did under Vista, Control Panel, Programs, Turn Windows Features On or Off

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the Web Platform Installer. Which will also allow you to easily install a number of other programs you might need for your dev environment, such as SQL Server Express, Visual Web Developer, Asp.Net MVC etc. Check it out...

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx